# If a heater was turned on its' own wire, would heating of the wire cause the resistance to increase, thus the current into the heater to decrease?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits

I'm thinking not, because;

A) It wouldn't make much sense in the real world because you'd need to avoid ever turning a heater towards its own wire, and you'd have to regulate the temperatures of any wires to make sure the current doesn't decrease

B) Am I right in saying that current in a series circuit (which the heater would be....?) is constant, so the increased resistance would have no effect whatsoever?

Just a thought that popped into my head. More looking for the reason that it wouldn't be true because I doubt it is.

Thanks.

Comment: The temperature would certainly increase greatly, because the house would catch fire, but honestly, in science the only correct answers are experimental... ;-)

Comment: B) is wrong in general; series current depends on the series resistance except in the ideal case of an ideal current source.  Otherwise, there would not be a market for these "real world" devices:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermistor

Comment: Unless I misunderstand the question, 'turning the heater onto its own heating elements' could only be done by putting it into a quasi-adiabatic enclosure, where temperature would then rise and rise until the heater breaks down.

Comment: No, sorry. I meant that the heater is turned on its own wire, heating up the wire that is connected to it.

Comment: You should know that when you turn on an incandescent light bulb, there is a large inrush of current due to the fact that the filament is cold and has relatively low resistance. As the filament heats up, its resistance also increases, causing the current to drop until it reaches a steady-state current. All this takes place in less than a second. This large initial inrush of electrical current is the reason that many older incandescent light bulbs fail when you first turn them on rather than after being on for minutes or hours.

Comment: @SamuelWeir so this would mean that the heater heating its own wire *would* decrease the current it experiences? Or is it just when the heater is turned on (like with the lightbulb) that any of this has a noticeable effect?

Comment: @Malnurtured - Yes, I would expect that if the heater is providing a constant voltage to its heating element then initially there would be a relatively large current which would then steadily decrease to some constant value as the heating element's temperature rises to its steady-state temperature.